# How to see exact fields that were modified in a Hyperledger Fabric transaction?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have an object called *Asset* with three fields: *id*, *name*, and *someInt*. On my deployed chaincode, I have a method that updates an asset’s name by providing its id. When I check the Hyperledger Explorer for transaction details created for this operation, in the appropriate Writes section, there is the correct key representing the asset’s id and value, which is a JSON representation of the whole object. Is it possible to see **exactly** what was modified in the given document, instead of being given the state of the object after the update?

I have tried exploring through related CouchDB but nothing seems to be right. I am using Hyperledger Explorer 1.1.8.